# Find the subset of predicators that are jointly most predicative to the target variable

Tags: regression, linear-model

Suppose there are $P$ cities around a central city, we their daily temperature readings for $N$ consecutive days; how could we find the set of $p \ll P$ cities that give us the smallest MSE with the temperature readings of the center city; that is, the temperature readings of this set of $p$ cities are jointly most predicative to the temperature readings of the central city.

I know this could be done by enumerating all $\binom{P}{p}=\frac{P!}{p!(P-p)!}$ combinations, but the runtime could be too expensive. Is there a way to develop an approximate solution to this problem?

As an example, if I have a dataset that looks like the following, where $p=5$ and $P=6$ then the output should be

```bash
Town1,Town2,Town3,Town4,Town5
```

The dataset:

```bash
Town1,Town2,Town3,Town4,Town5,Town6,Central
34,32,53,5,10,29,40
86,91,24,10,12,50,45
56,78,90,23,23,45,23
23,92,45,44,55,67,34
12,99,23,34,64,56,35
22,102,11,23,45,65,43
```

Comment: Why not the subset that is the entire set? That is, why not pick all of the variables?

Comment: @Dave This is the setting of the question. I am not sure why there is such setting.

Comment: Setting set by whom?

Comment: @Dave This is a bonus homework question. The original question is $p=2$ and $P=5$; after I solved it with the brute-force enumeration, the question further asks us whether we could come up with an approximate solution for $p \ll P$ and very large $P$.